# How can I use containers with a smart ptr?

Tags: c++

How can I use smart pointers with containers in my C++ file? For example, I can use a struct with `unique_ptr` in a `map`

```
struct tsExpStruct { int i; float b; void initialize(); };

typedef std::map< char, std::unique_ptr < tExpStruct > > mp;
```

or I can use just

```
typedef std::map< char, tExpStruct* > mp;
```

then create an object with `mp  m_MpMap;`
and destroy it with

```
void ASD::Destroy()
{
    for (const auto& it : m_MpMap)
        delete it.second;
    m_MpMap.clear();
}
```

Everything is okay, but when I use `unique_ptr` I can't use `delete it.second`. I know smart pointers are auto-cleaning. If I can use `unique_ptr` will there be a leak? I don't understand fully this topic.

Comment: RTFM `it.second.reset();`. You can omit the loop in your case.

Comment: Is there even a need to do that? Wouldn't the pointer automatically do the deletion when the map removes it?

Comment: When a `std::map`'s destructor is called, it calls the destructor of every key and value in the map. When the value type is a `tExpStruct*` raw pointer, that means you also have to manually call `delete it.second;` because just destroying a pointer doesn't `delete` the pointed-to object. When the value type is a `std::unique_ptr<tExpStruct>`, the `unique_ptr` destructor will destroy the pointed-to `tExpStruct` because that's the ownership model a `unique_ptr` is for.

Comment: @NathanPierson so when if i can `unique_ptr` my destroy func is just `m_MpMap.clear();` is true my friend?

Comment: @CILGINIMAM yes, simply clearing a `std::map` (or any contanier) will automatically destroy any smart pointer stored in it, and thus automatically `delete` the pointers the smart pointers are holding.

Comment: *"I know smart pointers are auto-cleaning."* -- You might want to review what you know since this is the answer to your question. A smart pointer automatically cleans up after itself. This means that there is no need to call `delete`. This means that there will not be a leak (unless something else in your program is broken).

Answer (score 4):

> If i can using unique_ptr will there be a leak?

No, unless you use a broken deleter or you call `std::unique_ptr::release`. All you need to do is:

```
m_MpMap.clear();
```

The destructor of each smart pointer will delete the pointer that it owns.